# Model and Controller's naming rule for irregular noun in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How should I name a controller if belonging model name is irregular noun?

For example, if a model name is "Child" then what name should I use? "Children" or "Childs"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For irregular language occurrences you can have a look at https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-0/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflections.rb

As you can see child will become **children**.